# Second Column with a combobox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get this sketch to work. I need to program the red things in this [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6dqx.png)

I use angularJS and bootstrap. This is the code right now:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <select name="" id="" ng-model="" ng-options="">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <select name="" id="" ng-model="" ng-options="">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <select name="" id="" ng-model="" ng-options="">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>                             
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" ng-model="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" ng-model="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" ng-model="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" ng-model="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="" ng-model="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to program a second column with textfields right next with a combobox above.

1 = combobox in angularjs

Kind regards and much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using col-md so I'm guessing you have bootstrap. You can nest another row in the column you already have so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- some inputs -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added some style to the div class with margin-left. Is this a OO solution? Or shall I use your code?

Comment: Well if you are using bootstrap this is the best solution as it will be responsive. This means on all devices the content will be visible, this might not be the case if you just use margin-left.

Comment: Thank you so much!